# Date Stored as Text Query Between and Higher

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to pull records from a mysql database which has everything stored as text.

The two fields i should query are stored like this format '19671011' type text and I need to select a range between and higher than.

How could I query a text field retrieving a particular month records?

```
select * from recordtable where birthday between () - () and anotherdate < '20081111'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing this to only return people for a certain month:

```
SELECT * FROM recordtable 
WHERE (MONTH(CAST(birthday AS DATE)) = 10)
AND CAST(anotherdate AS DATE) < CAST('20081111' AS DATE);
```

Here is a good link for SQL date calculations: 
http://mysql-tips.blogspot.com/2005/04/mysql-date-calculations.html

Comment: I need to select ****10** to return only people with birthdays that month.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant here.  Do you mean you only want to return people with birthdays in October?

Comment: Okay, I edited my original answer to return people with birthdays in a specific month, with thanks to user vbigham for coming up with the idea to use the date cast method.

Comment: you could alternatively use SUBSTRING to parse the dates `SUBSTRING('20081111',5,2)` Although using CAST will allow for more flexibility if the dates are not always the same format.

Answer (score 1):

You can try asking MySql to cast those string values as dates (assuming that all the strings are 8 chars it should work for the comparisons you need).

Like this:

```
CAST('20081111' AS DATE)
```

Then your query might become something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM recordtable 
WHERE CAST(birthday AS DATE) >= CAST('20050405' AS DATE)
AND CAST(birthday AS DATE) <= CAST('20111010' AS DATE)
AND CAST(anotherdate AS DATE) < CAST('20081111' AS DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly framed as a question, but let me try to answer. If the date field is always 8 characters stored YYYYMMDD, then you can just compare the fields as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the BETWEEN operator in vbigham's solution, as follows:

> You can try asking MySql to cast those string values as dates
>   (assuming that all the strings are 8 chars it should work for the
>   comparisons you need).
>
> Like this:
>
> CAST('20081111' AS DATE)
>
> Then your query might become something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM recordtable 
WHERE (CAST(birthday AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST('20050405' AS DATE) 
                                      AND CAST('20111010' AS DATE))
AND CAST(anotherdate AS DATE) < CAST('20081111' AS DATE);
```